# Adding pug-plain-loader configuration in vue.config.js

Tags: vue.js, webpack, pug, vue-cli-3, vue-loader

I have a project created through [Vue CLI](https://cli.vuejs.org/) and now I want to use [Pug](https://pugjs.org/) with my [Single File Components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html) i.e. the `.vue` files.

To do that I started following this [vue-loader documentation](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/pre-processors.html#pug) and installed `pug` and `pug-plain-loader` with the command `npm install -D pug pug-plain-loader`. And the next step there proposes inserting the follows in `webpack.config.js`

```js
// webpack.config.js -> module.rules
{
  test: /\.pug$/,
  loader: 'pug-plain-loader'
}
```

But, using Vue CLI, I do not have an explicit webpack config file, but `vue.config.js`.

So, how to add such a `pug-plain-loader` configuration in `vue.config.js` (preferably using [webpack-chain](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html#chaining-advanced))?

My current `vue.config.js` already featuring a `svg-loader` is as follows:

```js
module.exports = {
  // ...
  chainWebpack: (config) => {
    const svgRule = config.module.rule('svg')
    svgRule.uses.clear()
    svgRule
      .use('vue-svg-loader')
      .loader('vue-svg-loader')

    //TODO: add pug-plain-loader configuration here
  }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Accordingly with the example [here](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html#adding-a-new-loader), Vue CLI has it own way to define new rules in webpack. So this code seems to be the right way to define the pug loader (in your vue.config.js file - if doesn't exists, create it):

```
    module.exports = {
      chainWebpack: (config) => {
        // Pug Loader
        config.module
          .rule('pug')
          .test(/\.pug$/)
          .use('pug-plain-loader')
          .loader('pug-plain-loader')
          .end();
      },
    };
```

This worked for me c:

(this apply only in .vue files that have lang="pug" specified in template tag)

Comment: works perfect  put that in the vue.config.js and run `npm i -D pug pug-plain-loader` and it all works, just use <template lang="pug">, easy to convert from original html with https://html2jade.org/ (only hindrance is that <selfclosed-tags /> break it), works perfectly with vue logic